# Third party Facebook chat application?

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I've been sifting through Facebook's developer documentation recently, and found out that Facebook had deprecated their chat API back in 2014. With the SDK for various platforms, however, it still remains possible to send content through an installed version of the Messenger app. With this in mind, is there any way that Facebook's current tools (or any other third party ones) can be utilized to create a Facebook chat application?

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: to create a chat app you have many options. you can decide first your architecture then you select the chat server options. you have gsm, firebase, amazon, pubnub, you can options to even fo for your own server for this..

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question. I was asking if it is possible to create a Facebook chat application.

Comment: yes you can . https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that isn't what I was referring to. I was referring to creating a third party Facebook chat application which allows you to see which of your friends are online, and send and receive message to/from your friends (or groups). The link you provided provides information about how to integrate advertisements into your apps.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921056/facebook-messenger-bot-object-structure-for-java/40109660#40109660? Also you can check out my Facebook Messenger API framework here: https://github.com/Aurasphere/facebot